# without def main() = O, with def main() = X

Tags: python

I made following functions but it generates errors when I use main functions despite no error without usage of main function

```
def setup_name():
    print("Before we start...","\n"
          "What is your name?")
    char_name = input("Name : ").strip().capitalize()
    return char_name

def intro():
    print(cname," is building great walls now")
    print()

cname = setup_name()
intro()
```

But below gives me error

```
def setup_name():
    print("Before we start...","\n"
          "What is your name?")
    char_name = input("Name : ").strip().capitalize()
    return char_name

def intro():
    print(cname," is building great walls now")
    print()

def main():
    cname = setup_name()
    intro()
main()
```

To me, it seems no difference exist here so I think i need some sharp eyes.

Thanks!

Comment: It will help if you look at the error message.

Comment: `cname` is local to your `main` function in the second example, so intro can't access it. It was global in your first example. So, you see, global variables can be evil and should be avoided!

Comment: On a side note, your title is not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cname` is no longer scoped at the module level (its current scope is now  function `main`) in the second version, so you'll get a `NameError` when `intro` tries to use `cname`.

You'll need to explicitly pass `cname` to `intro`, to make it work in the second version.

See [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-scoping-rules).

Comment: woah! The hyperlinked resource is something I haven't covered yet! Thanks for the resource and comment! it really helped me!